# How to get time interval from SQL time date format in php

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I am getting two time intervals from a database, such as:

`PickUpDateTime = "2013-4-20 12:00:00"`
and `returndatetime ="2013-4-20 14:00:00"`.

How can I find the time interval between these two times in PHP?

Comment: Make sure you know what they are representing.  If these are in a local time zone, then you might be an hour off (positive or negative) when daylight savings time changes.  In general, you should only subtract datetimes to get a duration if you can guarantee that they are in the same offset, or are factoring the offset into your equation.  One easy way to do this, is to use UTC datetimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the to seconds, and subtract.

```
$date1 = strtotime($mysqldate1);
$date2 = strtotime($mysqldate2);
$diff_in_seconds = abs($date1 - $date2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u can use [Mysql TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, returndatetime, pickUpDateTime) as diffInSeconds FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtotime to convert them to timestamps. Then subtract/divide.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `TIMEDIFF()` a mysql function

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff